# Python Pandas join a few files

Tags: python, pandas

I import a few xlsx files into pandas dataframe. It works fine, but my problem that it copies all the data under each other (so I have 10 excel file with 100 lines = 1000 lines).

I need the Dataframe with 100 lines and 10 columns, so each file will be copied next to each other and not below.

Are there any ideas how to do it?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/folder/')

path = ('C:/Users/folder/')
files = os.listdir(path)

allNames = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    info = pd.read_excel(f,'Sheet1')
    allNames = allNames.append(info)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter ('Output.xlsx')
allNames.to_excel(writer, 'Copy')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can feed your spreadsheets as an array of dataframes directly to `pd.concat()`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/folder/')

path = ('C:/Users/folder/')
files = os.listdir(path)

allNames = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f,'Sheet1') for f in files], axis=1)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter ('Output.xlsx')
allNames.to_excel(writer, 'Copy')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stacking the tables vertically like this:

```
allNames = allNames.append(info)
```

You'll want to concatenate them horizontally like this:

```
allNames = pd.concat([allNames , info], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's very helpful!!